I have a json and I want to take it to java classes to be able to map it using quarkus and apache camel
I'm currently working with Apache Camel and Quarkus and consuming a microservice that has the following json as a response:
{
    "deviceStatusConnectorResponse": {
        "Body": {
            "Result": {
                "resultCode": 0,
                "resultDesc": "SUCCESS0001:Operation is successful",
                "resultData": {
                    "group": [
                        {
                            "imsi": "000000000000",
                            "isdn": "58000000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "group": [
                                {
                                    "vlrNum": "0000000000",
                                    "mscNum": "0000000000",
                                    "msPurgedForNonGprs": "FALSE",
                                    "vlrInHplmn": "TRUE",
                                    "vlrInHomeCountry": "TRUE",
                                    "vlrInArea": "TRUE",
                                    "requireCheckSS": "FALSE",
                                    "roamingRestrictInMscDueToUnsupportedFeature": "FALSE",
                                    "mscOrVlrAreaRoamingRestrict": "FALSE",
                                    "odBarredForUnsupportedCamel": "FALSE",
                                    "supportedCamelPhase1": "TRUE",
                                    "supportedCamelPhase2": "TRUE",
                                    "supportedCamelPhase3": "FALSE",
                                    "supportedCamelPhase4": "FALSE",
                                    "sriMsrnCfActive": "TRUE",
                                    "zoneCodeStatusAtMsc": "zoneCodesSupported",
                                    "longGroupIDSupported": "FALSE",
                                    "basicISTSupported": "FALSE",
                                    "istCommandSupported": "FALSE",
                                    "superChargerSupportedForGsm": "FALSE",
                                    "ecategoryAtMsc": "FALSE",
                                    "csupltime": "2024-04-30 16:36:39",
                                    "lsflag": "FALSE",
                                    "camelInduceBarringSMS": "FALSE",
                                    "roamBaocTs11": "FALSE",
                                    "mtrfSupported": "FALSE",
                                    "csmsisdnless": "FALSE",
                                    "csUplStatus": "Normal"
                                },
                                {
                                    "baocForVlrRestrict": "FALSE"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "\"Dynamic Status Information For GSM\""
                        },
                        {
                            "sgsnNum": "584240000204",
                            "sgsnAddressType": "IPV4",
                            "sgsnAddress": "186.166.144.3",
                            "sgsnInHplmn": "TRUE",
                            "msPurgedForGprs": "FALSE",
                            "sgsnInHomeCountry": "TRUE",
                            "sgsnInArea": "TRUE",
                            "roamingRestrictInSgsnDueToUnsupportedFeature": "FALSE",
                            "sgsnAreaRoamingRestrict": "FALSE",
                            "odBarredForUnsupportedCamelForGprs": "FALSE",
                            "psupltime": "2024-04-22 21:29:20",
                            "psmsisdnless": "FALSE",
                            "psUplStatus": "Normal",
                            "name": "\"Dynamic Status Information For GPRS\""
                        },
                        {
                            "imei": "861775059548540",
                            "mmehost": "mmecol03.mmegi65103.mme.epc.mnc004.mcc734.3gppnetwork.org",
                            "mmerealm": "epc.mnc004.mcc734.3gppnetwork.org",
                            "rattype": "EUTRAN",
                            "vplmn": "73404",
                            "purgedonmme": "FALSE",
                            "mmeUpdateLocationTime": "2024-04-22 21:29:05",
                            "mmeFeatureList": "0x0C000600",
                            "lastIDRorDSRFailed": "FALSE",
                            "singleRegistrationIndication": "FALSE",
                            "skipSubscriberDataIndicator": "TRUE",
                            "gprsSubscriptionDataIndicator": "FALSE",
                            "nodeTypeIndicator": "Single",
                            "initialAttachIndicator": "TRUE",
                            "pslcsNotSupportedByUE": "FALSE",
                            "imeisv": "76",
                            "imsvopsSessionsSupported": "UNKNOWN",
                            "uesrvccCapability": "UE-SRVCC-NOT-SUPPORTED",
                            "name": "\"Dynamic Status Information For MME\""
                        },
                        {
                            "imei": "861775059548540",
                            "lastIDRorDSRFailed": "FALSE",
                            "skipSubscriberDataIndicator": "FALSE",
                            "gprsSubscriptionDataIndicator": "FALSE",
                            "nodeTypeIndicator": "Single",
                            "initialAttachIndicator": "FALSE",
                            "pslcsNotSupportedByUE": "FALSE",
                            "imeisv": "76",
                            "purgedonsgsn": "FALSE",
                            "arearestrict": "FALSE",
                            "s4SGSNFeatureList": "0x00000000",
                            "imsvopsSessionsSupportedS4SGSN": "UNKNOWN",
                            "uesrvccCapabilityS4SGSN": "UE-SRVCC-NOT-SUPPORTED",
                            "name": "\"Dynamic Status Information For S4SGSN\""
                        },
                        {
                            "ueRegisterAtIMS": "FALSE",
                            "name": "\"Dynamic Status Information For IMS\""
                        },
                        {
                            "supportedCamelPhase3SGSN": "FALSE",
                            "supportedCamelPhase4SGSN": "FALSE",
                            "zoneCodeStatusAtSgsn": "zoneCodesSupported",
                            "superChargerSupportedForGprs": "FALSE"
                        },
                        {
                            "mceFforGSM": "FALSE",
                            "mnrf": "FALSE",
                            "mnrRforGSM": "No Reason for Non-GPRS",
                            "name": "\"Short Message Dynamic Data for GSM\""
                        },
                        {
                            "mceFforGPRS": "FALSE",
                            "mnrg": "FALSE",
                            "mnrRforGPRS": "No Reason",
                            "supportedShortMessageMTPP": "FALSE",
                            "supportedShortMessageMOPP": "FALSE",
                            "name": "\"Short Message Dynamic Data for GPRS\""
                        },
                        {
                            "mceFforIP": "FALSE",
                            "unri": "FALSE",
                            "unrr": "No Reason",
                            "urrpmme": "REACHABLE",
                            "urrpsgsn": "NOT_REACHABLE ",
                            "name": "\"Short Message Dynamic Data for IP\""
                        },
                        {
                            "barredSSAccess": "TRUE",
                            "barredOutgoingEntertainmentCall": "TRUE",
                            "barredOutgoingInformationCall": "TRUE",
                            "supGSMODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCallExHC": "TRUE",
                            "supGSMODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCall": "TRUE",
                            "supGSMODBBarredAllOutgoingCall": "TRUE",
                            "barredAllECT": "TRUE",
                            "barredChargeableECT": "TRUE",
                            "barredInternationalECT": "TRUE",
                            "barredInterzonalECT": "TRUE",
                            "barredDECT": "TRUE",
                            "barredMECT": "TRUE",
                            "name": "\"ODB Supported Features For GSM\""
                        },
                        {
                            "supGPRSODBBarredAllOutgoingCall": "TRUE",
                            "supGPRSODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCall": "TRUE",
                            "supGPRSODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCallExHC": "TRUE",
                            "barringofPacketOrientedServices": "TRUE",
                            "name": "\"ODB Supported Features For GPRS\""
                        },
                        {
                            "mscSupportedLCSCapabilitySet1": "FALSE",
                            "mscSupportedLCSCapabilitySet2": "FALSE",
                            "sgsnSupportedLCSCapabilitySet2": "FALSE",
                            "name": "\"Supported LCS\""
                        },
                        {
                            "alsdyn": "FALSE",
                            "vvdndyn": "FALSE",
                            "name": "\"Featured Service Supported Features\""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

However, I can't get this json into java. I tried using this page:
https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo
To take it, however at the log level I get something like this when I try to get the response with ObjectMapper:
String bodyResponse=exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
DeviceStatusConnectorResponse deviceStatusConnectorResponse =objectMapper.readValue(bodyResponse, DeviceStatusConnectorResponse.class);
String jsonDeviceStatusConnectorResponse=objectMapper.writeValueAsString(deviceStatusConnectorResponse);
log.info("Respuesta Microservicio DeviceStatusConnector "+jsonDeviceStatusConnectorResponse);

What the logs tell me:
{"deviceStatusConnectorResponse":{"Body":{"Result":{"resultCode":0,"resultDesc":"SUCCESS0001:Operation is successful","resultData":{"group":[{"imsi":"734042209390131","isdn":"584242374781","name":null,"sgsnNum":null,"sgsnAddressType":null,"sgsnAddress":null,"sgsnInHplmn":null,"msPurgedForGprs":null,"sgsnInHomeCountry":null,"sgsnInArea":null,"roamingRestrictInSgsnDueToUnsupportedFeature":null,"sgsnAreaRoamingRestrict":null,"odBarredForUnsupportedCamelForGprs":null,"psupltime":null,"psmsisdnless":null,"psUplStatus":null,"imei":null,"mmehost":null,"mmerealm":null,"rattype":null,"vplmn":null,"purgedonmme":null,"mmeUpdateLocationTime":null,"mmeFeatureList":null,"lastIDRorDSRFailed":null,"singleRegistrationIndication":null,"skipSubscriberDataIndicator":null,"gprsSubscriptionDataIndicator":null,"nodeTypeIndicator":null,"initialAttachIndicator":null,"pslcsNotSupportedByUE":null,"imeisv":null,"imsvopsSessionsSupported":null,"uesrvccCapability":null,"purgedonsgsn":null,"arearestrict":null,"s4SGSNFeatureList":null,"imsvopsSessionsSupportedS4SGSN":null,"uesrvccCapabilityS4SGSN":null,"ueRegisterAtIMS":null,"supportedCamelPhase3SGSN":null,"supportedCamelPhase4SGSN":null,"zoneCodeStatusAtSgsn":null,"superChargerSupportedForGprs":null,"mceFforGSM":null,"mnrf":null,"mnrRforGSM":null,"mceFforGPRS":null,"mnrg":null,"mnrRforGPRS":null,"supportedShortMessageMTPP":null,"supportedShortMessageMOPP":null,"mceFforIP":null,"unri":null,"unrr":null,"urrpmme":null,"urrpsgsn":null,"barredSSAccess":null,"barredOutgoingEntertainmentCall":null,"barredOutgoingInformationCall":null,"supGSMODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCallExHC":null,"supGSMODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCall":null,"supGSMODBBarredAllOutgoingCall":null,"barredAllECT":null,"barredChargeableECT":null,"barredInternationalECT":null,"barredInterzonalECT":null,"barredDECT":null,"barredMECT":null,"supGPRSODBBarredAllOutgoingCall":null,"supGPRSODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCall":null,"supGPRSODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCallExHC":null,"barringofPacketOrientedServices":null,"mscSupportedLCSCapabilitySet1":null,"mscSupportedLCSCapabilitySet2":null,"sgsnSupportedLCSCapabilitySet2":null,"alsdyn":null,"vvdndyn":null,"vlrNum":null,"mscNum":null,"msPurgedForNonGprs":null,"vlrInHplmn":null,"vlrInHomeCountry":null,"vlrInArea":null,"requireCheckSS":null,"roamingRestrictInMscDueToUnsupportedFeature":null,"mscOrVlrAreaRoamingRestrict":null,"odBarredForUnsupportedCamel":null,"supportedCamelPhase1":null,"supportedCamelPhase2":null,"supportedCamelPhase3":null,"supportedCamelPhase4":null,"sriMsrnCfActive":null,"zoneCodeStatusAtMsc":null,"longGroupIDSupported":null,"basicISTSupported":null,"istCommandSupported":null,"superChargerSupportedForGsm":null,"ecategoryAtMsc":null,"csupltime":null,"lsflag":null,"camelInduceBarringSMS":null,"roamBaocTs11":null

This is how I am organizing my classes according to what I got from the previous page:
DeviceStatusConnectorResponse
public class DeviceStatusConnectorResponse {

    @JsonProperty("deviceStatusConnectorResponse")
    private DeviceStatusConnectorResponseBody deviceStatusConnectorResponse;
}

DeviceStatusConnectorResponseBody
public class DeviceStatusConnectorResponseBody {

    @JsonProperty("Body")
   private BodyResponse bodyResponse;
}

BodyResponse
public class BodyResponse {

    @JsonProperty("Result")
    private Result result;
}

Result
public class Result {

    @JsonProperty("resultCode")
    public int resultCode;

    @JsonProperty("resultDesc")
    public String resultDesc;

    @JsonProperty("resultData")
    public ResultData resultData;
}

ResultData
public class ResultData {

    @JsonProperty("group")
    private ArrayList<Group> group;
}

public class Group{
    public String imsi;
    public String isdn;
    public ArrayList<Group> group;
    public String name;
    public String sgsnNum;
    public String sgsnAddressType;
    public String sgsnAddress;
    public String sgsnInHplmn;
    public String msPurgedForGprs;
    public String sgsnInHomeCountry;
    public String sgsnInArea;
    public String roamingRestrictInSgsnDueToUnsupportedFeature;
    public String sgsnAreaRoamingRestrict;
    public String odBarredForUnsupportedCamelForGprs;
    public String psupltime;
    public String psmsisdnless;
    public String psUplStatus;
    public String imei;
    public String mmehost;
    public String mmerealm;
    public String rattype;
    public String vplmn;
    public String purgedonmme;
    public String mmeUpdateLocationTime;
    public String mmeFeatureList;
    public String lastIDRorDSRFailed;
    public String singleRegistrationIndication;
    public String skipSubscriberDataIndicator;
    public String gprsSubscriptionDataIndicator;
    public String nodeTypeIndicator;
    public String initialAttachIndicator;
    public String pslcsNotSupportedByUE;
    public String imeisv;
    public String imsvopsSessionsSupported;
    public String uesrvccCapability;
    public String purgedonsgsn;
    public String arearestrict;
    public String s4SGSNFeatureList;
    public String imsvopsSessionsSupportedS4SGSN;
    public String uesrvccCapabilityS4SGSN;
    public String ueRegisterAtIMS;
    public String supportedCamelPhase3SGSN;
    public String supportedCamelPhase4SGSN;
    public String zoneCodeStatusAtSgsn;
    public String superChargerSupportedForGprs;
    public String mceFforGSM;
    public String mnrf;
    public String mnrRforGSM;
    public String mceFforGPRS;
    public String mnrg;
    public String mnrRforGPRS;
    public String supportedShortMessageMTPP;
    public String supportedShortMessageMOPP;
    public String mceFforIP;
    public String unri;
    public String unrr;
    public String urrpmme;
    public String urrpsgsn;
    public String barredSSAccess;
    public String barredOutgoingEntertainmentCall;
    public String barredOutgoingInformationCall;
    public String supGSMODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCallExHC;
    public String supGSMODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCall;
    public String supGSMODBBarredAllOutgoingCall;
    public String barredAllECT;
    public String barredChargeableECT;
    public String barredInternationalECT;
    public String barredInterzonalECT;
    public String barredDECT;
    public String barredMECT;
    public String supGPRSODBBarredAllOutgoingCall;
    public String supGPRSODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCall;
    public String supGPRSODBBarredOutgoingInternationalCallExHC;
    public String barringofPacketOrientedServices;
    public String mscSupportedLCSCapabilitySet1;
    public String mscSupportedLCSCapabilitySet2;
    public String sgsnSupportedLCSCapabilitySet2;
    public String alsdyn;
    public String vvdndyn;
    public String vlrNum;
    public String mscNum;
    public String msPurgedForNonGprs;
    public String vlrInHplmn;
    public String vlrInHomeCountry;
    public String vlrInArea;
    public String requireCheckSS;
    public String roamingRestrictInMscDueToUnsupportedFeature;
    public String mscOrVlrAreaRoamingRestrict;
    public String odBarredForUnsupportedCamel;
    public String supportedCamelPhase1;
    public String supportedCamelPhase2;
    public String supportedCamelPhase3;
    public String supportedCamelPhase4;
    public String sriMsrnCfActive;
    public String zoneCodeStatusAtMsc;
    public String longGroupIDSupported;
    public String basicISTSupported;
    public String istCommandSupported;
    public String superChargerSupportedForGsm;
    public String ecategoryAtMsc;
    public String csupltime;
    public String lsflag;
    public String camelInduceBarringSMS;
    public String roamBaocTs11;
    public String mtrfSupported;
    public String csmsisdnless;
    public String csUplStatus;
    public String baocForVlrRestrict;
}


What's the problem? You deserialized and serialized the payload successfully if this is your actual log. If you want to get rid of the null values in the generated json, you can annotate the POJO classes or properties with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL). The POJO deviceStatusConnectorResponse looks fine for me.
